# Routing error after using :path option

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model called 'users' that I changed to 'people' in the url.

Routes.rb

```
resources :users, :path => "people"
```

Everything works fine except when creating a new user I get a routing error and it redirects to '/users', instead of creating the user and going to '/people/:id'.

```
No route matches [POST] "/users"
```

If I take

```
:path => "people"
```

out of the routes it works fine.

The form looks like:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@user) do |f| %>
```

and here is the controlller:

```
def create
@user = User.create(user_params)
if @user.save
    redirect_to @user
  else
    redirect_to root_path
end    
end
```

Comment: where's the code that does the redirect?

Comment: Edited with redirect code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is happening is in your route file, you are changing what the users route is routing to with your `path: 'people'` call.

However, since rails sees that the model you're creating is called `User`, it assumes that it should post that to `/users`.

While, I'm not completely familiar with simple_form, this works with normal rails:

```
<%= form_for @user, url: users_path do |f| %>
```

Notice the `url: users_path` option, what this does is explicitly link the form to the user path, aka `/testers`.

--Cheers